# Entity Framework Core : nonstop initializations

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, hangfire

I'm using EF Core with npsql (postgres provider). There is a weird pattern in the logging while I'm using this on a hangfire server I have where EF keeps getting initialized every 8 seconds on the dot. I can't find what is causing these contexts to be initialized all the time. I'm using Hangfire with Redis, so I wouldn't expect that to trigger these logs.

What can I do to understand what's causing the initializations and how to stop them (if necessary)

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.7 initialized 'MyContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.5+9d79af6e2586d5d28da253ac075706a5575a1743' with options: SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled using snake-case naming  (culture=)
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.7 initialized 'MyContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.5+9d79af6e2586d5d28da253ac075706a5575a1743' with options: SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled using snake-case naming  (culture=)
```

Comment: Can you print the stack trace when its getting initialized?

Comment: Do you have other logs after/between these? Like sql commands or something? The log you see indicates that some code is creating `MyContext` instances and doing something with them (for instance health checks, if there is no your background service running doing something periodically every 8 seconds).

Comment: I don't see any other logs unfortunately, it's just a sequence of initialization. I have sql logging enabled on my debug environment so if it was actually executing anything, I would've seen it logged @IvanStoev I do have periodically running workers, however none of them is 8 seconds, there is a 5 second one which is close though. But their run times aren't overlapping

I unfortunately don't have a stack trace, as there is no error and I'm not seeing what exactly is initializing the context SlackGroverglow

Comment: Do you have an hangfire dashboard open when seing this behaviour ? The dashboard polls the app every few seconds.

Comment: @jbl I don't have the dashboard open, however like I've mentioned, I am using a redis adapter and not the default one, so it shouldnt be going through that, afaik